# Ubuntu installation interrupted

Tags: system-installation

I was installing ubuntu from usb fdd alongside with windows 7. When I left my laptop for a few minutes, my toddler pushed the power button of my laptop. The screen was black/blank when I got back. Now I've trying to fix it. I want to reinstall it but I couldn't, but it won't boot from usb now.
What should I do?

Comment: Format the USB and do everything again. Format the partition you wanna install ubuntu on aswell.

Comment: Have you tried to access your BIOS when starting your laptop and choosing to boot from your USB? Everything should be just fine, unless some files have been corrupted. In this case, you should prepare a new bootable flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do in the case of an interrupted install is just to start over as trying to fix a partial install will lead you into dependency hell.

Therefore:

- Boot again from USB
- take "something else"
- Re-format the EXT4 partitions you created *taking care not to remove your Windows partitions*
- let the install finish *while the toddler is sleeping.*